# How to set key to value in array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have this string: `'#d48888,abc.com,repeat,top left,scroll';`

How do I convert this string to an array like this: `Array('color'=>#d48888, 'href'=>abc.com, ... )`?

Comment: note: `Array('color'=>#d48888, 'href'=>abc.com, ... )` is a php array

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

First split the string on the comma basis:

```
var string = '#d48888,abc.com,repeat,top left,scroll';
var arrayOfString =   str.split(',');
```

Use another array to store the key => Value pair:

```
var newArray = {};
newArray.color = arrayOfString[0];
newArray.href = arrayOfString[1];
newArray.action = arrayOfString[2];
newArray.top = arrayOfString[3];
newArray.scroll = arrayOfString[4];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a javascript object, not an array.

```
var tmpObj = {};
var str = '#d48888,abc.com,repeat,top left,scroll';

var aryStr = str.split(','); //Splits the string on a delimeter
tmpObj.color = aryStr[0]; //sets the 'color' property
tmpObj.href = aryStr[1]; //sets the 'href' property
//Complete object

console.log(aryStr); //prints out the object and its properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a array with keys and then loop and save a object with the key and the value that you want

Try something like:

```
var string_array= '#d48888,abc.com,repeat,top left,scroll'.split(',');
var array_key=["color","href","background-repeat","background-position","overflow"];
var newobj = {};
$.each(string_array,function(i,v){
 newobj[array_key[i]] = v;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1qbu4brs/

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use PHP, use `explode(<delimeter>,string)` to convert your string into an array, and then add into the PHP array (which is really a map):

[PHP explode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "#d48888,abc.com,repeat,top left,scroll";
$aryStr = explode(",", $str);

$finalAry = [
    "color" => $aryStr[0];
    "href" => $aryStr[1];
    //complete
];
```